# CodeIgniter session array access

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

I'm deciding on the benefits of using Codeigniter's Built-in sessions but have come to somewhat of a roadblock. Given the following code:

```
if( ! isset( $_SESSION['array']['array_element'] ) ) {
  $_SESSION['array']['array_element'] = $value;
}
```

if there a way to do this in Codeigniter session functions? preferably in the same two lines of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(!isset($this->session->userdata('item'))){
    $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
 }
```

Keep in mine new data is an array as such

```
 $newdata = array(
    'username'  => 'johndoe',
    'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
    'logged_in' => TRUE
 );
```

Comment: but 'item' is an element in a multidimensional array, and $newdata is a simple value, (again, in a multidimensional array), not an array itself. This works fine for a 1 level array but that's not my question